# update the changes in local workspace from svn repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I want to update my local work space with recent changes from SVN repository...

I tried with Export after that I am unable to find the changes until and unless I can`t update

Note: I don`t want to check out entire project only changes want to update..

Thanks

Comment: synchronize first by svn and get update what you want.

Comment: Did you check out the project using Eclipse? In other words, is your Eclipse Project already associated with the SVN repository?

Comment: Win- Can you please provide me the steps. I want to see which class effected and those are critical or not then i want to update